# How to apply to the every ith column of the jth matrix in a list of matrices

Tags: r, list, matrix, lapply, sapply

I am  trying to write some functions that operates on matrices within a list, such that a particular operation is performed for a set of columns within each matrix for every matrix in the list. The code deals with a project involving data that isn't mine, so I can't share the exact code and data. However, here is some code for a reproducible example of the struggles I'm having. Can anyone enlighten me on how to accomplish an ith column in jth matrix function using *apply?

```
 ### This will generate a list of data frames so there is an reproducible example.
list = lapply(seq(1:10), function(x) dplyr::sample_n(iris[,1:4], size=30))

### List the number of columns per matrix for ease
n_i = 4

### If I manually set the list index the function works fine (for that list). Let's suppose I want the residuals for all variables being predicted by Sepal.Width
get.residuals = function(i) {
 residuals(lm(y ~ ., data=cbind.data.frame(y=list[[5]][,i], list[[5]][,2])))
}

### This gives the residuals for each variable given all other variables. This doesn't make sense here of course.
sapply(c(1,3,4), function(i) get.residuals(i))

### Looks perfect. The output is the residuals for three variables specified in c(1,3,4) being predicted by Sepa.Width

### Now I want to extract the residuals for every column i in each matrix j in the list. I won't show them  all here, but I've tried probably 50 different variations of the functions and uses of lapply,sapply,apply,and for loops and just can't seem to get it to do what I'd like. 

### As an example of an attempt that thows the error "Error in terms.formula(formula, data = data) : '.' in formula and no 'data' argument

get.residuals = function(i,j) {
 residuals(lm(y ~ ., data=cbind.data.frame(y=list[[j]][,i], list[[j]][,2])))
}

lapply(list, function(j) get.residuals(i))
```

Comment: Based on the same logic you need `lapply(list, function(l) sapply(c(1, 3, 4), function(j) residuals(lm(y ~ ., data = data.frame(y = l[,1], l[,2])))))`

Comment: It should be `data = data.frame(y = l[,j]`

Comment: Thank you! This seems to work well for the example provided and adapted to the needs with my real data with ease.